# I want to display an error if the employee had an account already

Tags: mysql, vb.net, adodb

Here is my code:

```
 rs.Open("Select * from tbl_emp_security WHERE Emp_ID='" & EmpID_account.Text & "'", con)
        If EmpID_account.Text = LVempaccount.Items(rs(0).Value) Then
            MsgBox("this employee have existing account")
        Else
            user_account.Text = "Emp" & Lname_account.Text
            passRandom()
    End If
```

Is if the employee try to add an account and if he had already... the messagebox will appear but if none. It proceeds to the next line..

`empid_accout.text` is the textbox that I am comparing to the first item on table.

`lvempaccount.tems(rs(0),value)` is the item that on the 1st column the employee id on the table

Comment: So what error are you getting.

Comment: Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.

Comment: Can you provide more detail, presumably other code. For example what is rs and LVempaccount?

Comment: rs.open is for the adodb record set and the lvempaccount is the listview for saving the employee ID,username,password,etc

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your code as follows

Hope it helps

```
Dim OutDs AS new Dataset
OutDS = ("Select * from tbl_emp_security WHERE Emp_ID='" & EmpID_account.Text & "'", con)

If OutDs isnot nothing andalso OutDs.Table.Rows.Count > 0  Then
            MsgBox("this employee have existing account")
        Else
            user_account.Text = "Emp" & Lname_account.Text
            passRandom()
    End If
```

If the Select Query returns a dataset , it means it has value so i used this way..!